Questions about matrix multiplication being identity matrix
Say I have an nxd matrix, X, where n is the number of rows and d is the number of features.
If I have the equation X(X^TX)^-1 X^T, can I simplify it like this?
X(X^T X)^-1 X^T
= X X^-1 (X^T)^-1 X^T (step 1)
= I*I (specifically, is this step allowed?) (step 2)
= I?

where I is the identity matrix.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This robot is stupid : your question is clear ! You can do it iff matrix $X$ is square... and moreover invertible. Otherwise it is meaningless to say that a non-square matrix has an inverse matrix.

@JeanMarie thank you!! So, in this case, the simplification is incorrect right? Since I assumed matrix X is nxd and, hence, not necessarily square.

That's it ! In fact, $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ is called "Moore Penrose inverse"

@JeanMarie thanks! just to clarify, would the end result still be the identity matrix (in what I showed above)? it's just that my step 1 would not be allowed right?

@dooder Not in general. If $n > d$, for example, then the whole matrix is $n \times n$, but each matrix in the product have rank at most $d$, hence the product has rank at most $d$. It can't be the $n \times n$ identity, which has rank $n$.

Hey, dooder, did it occur to you to try an example? Make up a $2\times1$ matrix, say, do your calculation, see whether you get the $2\times2$ identity matrix. You don't have to ask anybody, you can work it out all by yourself, just give it a try!
